filter loki logs in Grafana by daily time range
I am using Grafana to display log messages from Loki / Promtail.
I want to exclude log entries (from a Laravel old style log file) by a daily time range - e.g. from 23:00:00 -- 00:05:00. So this should be for all selected time ranges independent from the choosen interval in Grafana and not related to "now" like here.
For the time being my query is just:
{job="varlogs", filename="/var/www/pls.axxteq.de/storage/logs/laravel.log"} |= `Error` 


To do such a filtration you should introduce a label that will contain hour of the log's associated timestamp, and the filter based on the value of that label:
{job="varlogs", filename="/var/www/pls.axxteq.de/storage/logs/laravel.log"} |= `Error`
 | label_format log_message_hour=`{{ date "15" __timestamp__ }}`
 | log_message_hour >= 5 
 | log_message_hour <= 23

Here template function date is used, to format timestamp of the log into to contain only hour (parameter "15" stands for hours in 24-hour format in shittyclever date formatting of Go)
